# How do I configure my asp.net core 2.2 app so that wordpress loads in its own subfolder instead of root?

Tags: wordpress, asp.net-core, peachpie

I'm using asp.net core 2.2 and the latest peachpie and wordpress repo at https://github.com/iolevel/wpdotnet-sdk. I just want to configure wordpress to load in a folder vs. root - ie. https://my.examplesite.com/content vs. https://my.examplesite.com

I feel like I have the hard stuff done - I grabbed the projects from peachpie's working repo, incorporated them into my own solution and wordpress works if I run the app. My app works as expected if I comment out the app.UseWordPress() from startup.cs. The only problem is I'd like my existing app to run at root and wordpress to run in a subfolder - ie. https://my.examplesite.com/content vs. https://my.examplesite.com. Right now if I enable app.UseWordPress() then my app can't be reached.

Ideally users can't reach the abovee wordpress content without first logging into the asp.net core app via identity.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `app.Map` to create a new branch for your pipeline

```
app.Map(new PathString("/content"), wordpressApp =>
{
    wordpressApp.UseWordPress();
});
```

Comment: I'd tried that already and got an error:
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.

I kept messing with it and realized it didn't like me putting in /content. I tried explicitly putting in a /content/index.php and it worked. I then went back and just put /content/ and it also worked, but /content gives me that error

Comment: @Mythprod can you post an issue on https://github.com/iolevel/wpdotnet-sdk/issues please ?

Comment: Same issue here and just adding "/" at the end of the path like PathString("/content/") solved the problem