# Protecting & integrating peachpie wordpress installation in asp.net core 2.2 app

Tags: wordpress, asp.net-core, peachpie

Related [to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58055670/how-do-i-configure-my-asp-net-core-2-2-app-so-that-wordpress-loads-in-its-own-su), I'd like to do 2 things with my new peachpie / WordPress project I've imported into my existing asp.net 2.2 application:

- I'd like to protect it with the same identity engine that I'm using to authenticate the rest of my site. I've set up a new branch for the WordPress pipeline but I'd like the WordPress content to be viewable only by users who've logged in
- I'd like to pull in WordPress pages into razor pages as partials. [This page](https://www.peachpie.io/2018/07/render-php-file-in-razor-view.html) describes how to do this by referencing PHP scripts directly but I'm not sure what I would use to display a WordPress content page?

Edit: Actually if I can get help solving bullet #2 I think it may take care of #1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pull in a WordPress page into a Razor page a la partial, I used jquery's .load and targeted the page's #content id of the div (pulling in the entire page re-styled the entire app) - you'll see a #page and #content div in all WordPress pages by default.

```
$('#loadPage').load(pageAddress + " #content");
```

To both protect it and give it its own route instead of root, I used this in my Configure method in startup.cs.

```
    app.MapWhen(context => context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/content"), wp => 
    {
        wp.Map(new PathString("/content"), wpMapper =>
        {
            wpMapper.UseWordPress();
        });

    });
```

This made the WordPress installation accessible from /content vs. root and protected all of the WordPress content behind the same credential engine I'm using for my ASP.NET Core application.

Now I have WordPress running in ASP.NET Core and incorporated it into razor pages and protected its content from users who aren't authenticated. Quite the little chore but hopefully this helps others who choose to use PeachPie with WordPress and ASP.NET Core (i'm using 2.2 if interesting).